# Problem with printing in Java

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have an application which talks to USB printer and prints out the receipt once a sale is completed. I have no problem with connecting to the printer and printing something. THe problem i have now is when i do some printing i could see only a part of my message gets printed on the receipt. I have attached the code i am using. Please help me to see the full printed receipt :)

--CODE--

```
package utilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;   
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;    
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;    
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;  
import java.awt.print.Printable;    
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;  
import java.awt.Color;  
import java.awt.Graphics;  
import java.awt.Graphics2D;      
public class ReceiptPrinter implements Printable {  
    private JFrame printFrame;  
    private String waitMsg;  
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;`  

    /** Inner class for the actual printed object */
    class PrintFrame extends JFrame {

        PrintFrame(String msg) {
            setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));

            jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

            jTextArea1.setColumns(80);

            jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);

            jTextArea1.setRows(5);

            jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);

            jTextArea1.setText(msg);

            add(jTextArea1);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    /** Creates a new instance of ReceiptPrinter with a default wait message */
    public ReceiptPrinter() {
        waitMsg = "Wait for the printer to finish\nClick the OK button when done";
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ReceiptPrinter with a wait message.
     *
     * @param   msg     the wait message
     */
    public ReceiptPrinter(String msg) {
        waitMsg = msg;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the actual message to the receipt printer - does not wait.
     *
     * @param   msg     the actual message to be printed
     */
    public void printIt(String msg) {
        printIt(msg, false);
    }

    /**
     * Sends the actual message to the receipt printer.
     *
     * @param   msg     the actual message to be printed
     * @param   wait    show JOptionPane to wait for print to finish
     */
    public void printIt(String msg, boolean wait) {
        printFrame = new PrintFrame(msg);

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat format = job.defaultPage();
        format.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
        //double width = format.getWidth();
        System.out.println(format.getImageableX()+","+format.getImageableY());

        job.setPrintable(this, format);

        try {
            job.print();
            if (wait) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, waitMsg, "Information",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //printFrame.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Print method required by Printable interface.
     *
     * @param   g       the graphics context
     * @param   format  the page format
     * @param   pagenum the page number requested to print
     * @return  int     flag indicating page existance
     */

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pagenum) {
        if (pagenum > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        //g.translate(0, 150);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Print the entire visible contents of a java.awt.Frame */
        printFrame.printAll(g2d);
        //g.translate((int) format.getImageableX(),
          //      (int) format.getImageableY());
        //printFrame.paint(g);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

}
```

And the main function where i call this class is

```
package utilities;
import forms_helper.global_variables;  
import java.awt.Dimension;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PrintTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {  
    private ReceiptPrinter receiptPrinter = new ReceiptPrinter();  
    private FileOutputStream fos;  
    public PrintTest() {  
        initComponents();  
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));  
        pack();  
        try {  
            fos = new FileOutputStream("USB002");    
        }  
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot open file\n" + e.getMessage(),  
                   "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
        }  
    }`  

    private void initComponents() {
        openButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        display = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        openButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11));
        openButton.setText("Open");
        openButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                openButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(openButton);
        openButton.setBounds(151, 120, 80, 23);

        display.setColumns(20);
        display.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(display);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        jScrollPane1.setBounds(10, 10, 220, 92);

        exitButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11));
        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(exitButton);
        exitButton.setBounds(10, 120, 70, 23);

        pack();
    }

    private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unable to close printer port",
                    "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        dispose();
    }

    private void openButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // this section attempts to send the BEL character to the printer port
        byte bel = 0x07;
        try {
            fos.write(bel);
            fos.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error trying to write\n" + e.getMessage(),
                    "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    // this section appends the BEL to  the printed message and sends it to the Windows printer
        //String msg = "test \n test";
        String msg=global_variables.msg;
        msg += ((char) 0x07);

        receiptPrinter.printIt(msg);
    // this section displays a hex dump of the printed message
    // note that the BEL is being converted to a box and that
    // is what actually prints on the printer instead of the beep
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i += 5) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if ((i + j) < msg.length()) {
                    int x = msg.charAt(i + j);
                    display.append(String.format("%02x ", x));
                }
            }
            display.append("   ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i + j < msg.length()) {
                    char c = msg.charAt(i + j);
                    display.append(String.format(" %c", c));
                }
            }
            display.append("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PrintTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JTextArea display;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton openButton;

}
```

When i print it i am getting the image like this
[image]

Actual content was something like this
[image]

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: No problem. You might look at the `Graphics` clipping bounds compared with `getImageableWidth` & `getImageableHeight`.

Comment: what do you mean ? i dont get you. can u explain tel me more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you tell me more?

Compare the rectangle returned by `g.getClipBounds()` to the `getImageableWidth()` and `getImageableHeight()` found in the [`PageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html). It looks like your image it getting clipped to the printers default `Paper` size.

Comment: bound:java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=-1,width=61,height=3681]

getImageableWidth():60.80315017700195  

getImageableHeight():697.6063232421875

Comment: This appears consistent with `PageFormat.PORTRAIT`; you could try `PageFormat.LANDSCAPE`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the problem, but I seem to recall when working with Graphics objects, you need to 'undo' all of the changes you did to it when you are done. So you need to add this line at the end of the print method

```
g2d.translate(-pf.getImageableX(), -pf.getImageableY());
```

The print method can be called many times even for the same page - maybe you're just translating the Graphics object too far.